# How to Fix a Tomcat Application Not Accepting TLS 1.0 connections any longer

Tags: ssl

My understanding is that you can add:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

to the java options, but I am not sure where this specifically gets added (e.g. what file and where in that file, and where that file might be located).

I'm not a developer and don't have experience with SSL, though I do have access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

That flag is a Java option, and must be fed to Tomcat when it starts. The specific way to do it will depend upon your operating system. If you are running Tomcat as a Windows service, you must modify the service. See [Tomcat Windows Service How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html). I recommend using `Tomcat7w.exe` in the Tomcat bin subdirectory as that gives you a nice GUI. Then go to the Java tab and put that fragment at the end of Java Options.

For Unix, you will need to edit the relevant batch file. There is more than one way to do this, but as a non-developer the simplest option is to add that fragment to `catalina.sh` in the Tomcat bin subdirectory, as part of JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it without luck.  Looks like we may not even be using tomcat for what's being affected by this but apache.

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue is I have Python 2.7.0 which may be an issue with TLS 1.1.